# Store web scraping results in DataFrame or dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm taking an online course, and I'm trying to automate the process capturing the course structure for my personal notes, which I keep locally in a Markdown file.

Here's an example chapter:

[image]

And here's a sample of how the HTML looks:

```
  <!-- Header of the chapter -->
  <div class="chapter__header">
      <div class="chapter__title-wrapper">
        <span class="chapter__number">
          <span class="chapter-number">1</span>
        </span>
        <h4 class="chapter__title">
          Introduction to Experimental Design
        </h4>
          <span class="chapter__price">
            Free
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="dc-progress-bar dc-progress-bar--small chapter__progress">
        <span class="dc-progress-bar__text">0%</span>
        <div class="dc-progress-bar__bar chapter__progress-bar">
          <span class="dc-progress-bar__fill" style="width: 0%;"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <p class="chapter__description">
    An introduction to key parts of experimental design plus some power and sample size calculations.
  </p>
  <!-- !Header of the chapter -->

<!-- Body of the chapter -->
  <ul class="chapter__exercises hidden">
      <li class="chapter__exercise ">
        <a class="chapter__exercise-link" href="https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/experimental-design-in-r/introduction-to-experimental-design?ex=1">
          <span class="chapter__exercise-icon exercise-icon ">
            <img width="23" height="23" src="https://cdn.datacamp.com/main-app/assets/courses/icon_exercise_video-3b15ea50771db747f7add5f53e535066f57d9f94b4b0ebf1e4ddca0347191bb8.svg" alt="Icon exercise video" />
          </span>
          <h5 class="chapter__exercise-title" title='Intro to Experimental Design'>Intro to Experimental Design</h5>
          <span class="chapter__exercise-xp">
            50 xp
          </span>
</a>      </li>
```

So far, I've used `BeautifulSoup` to pull out all the relevant information:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.datacamp.com/courses/experimental-design-in-r'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

lesson_outline = soup.find_all(['h4', 'li'])

outline_list = []

for item in lesson_outline:
    attributes = item.attrs
    try:
        class_type = attributes['class'][0]
        if class_type == 'chapter__title':
            outline_list.append(item.text.strip())
        if class_type == 'chapter__exercise':
            lesson_name = item.find('h5').text
            lesson_link = item.find('a').attrs['href']
            outline_list.append(lesson_name)
            outline_list.append(lesson_link)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

This gives me a list like this:

```
['Introduction to Experimental Design', 'Intro to Experimental Design', 'https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/experimental-design-in-r/introduction-to-experimental-design?ex=1',...]
```

My goal is to put this all into an `.md` file that would look something like this:

```
# Introduction to Experimental Design

* [Intro to Experimental Design](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/experimental-design-in-r/introduction-to-experimental-design?ex=1)
* ['A basic experiment](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/experimental-design-in-r/introduction-to-experimental-design?ex=2)
```

My question is: What's the best way to structure this data so that I can easily access it later on when I'm writing the text file? Would it be better to have a DataFrame with columns `chapter`, `lesson`, `lesson_link`? A DataFrame with a MultiIndex? A nested dictionary? If it were a dictionary, what should I name the keys? Or is there another option I'm missing? Some sort of database?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I see it right, you're currently appending every element in order of it's appearance to the list `outline_list`. But obviously you don't have 1, but instead 3 types of distinct data:

- `chapter__title`
- `chapter__exercise.name`
- `chapter__exercise.link`

Each title can have multiple exercises, which are always a pair of `name` and `link`. Since you also want to keep the data in this structure for your text-file, you can come up with any structure that represents this hierarchy. An example:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict

url = 'https://www.datacamp.com/courses/experimental-design-in-r'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

lesson_outline = soup.find_all(['h4', 'li'])

# Using OrderedDict assures that the order of the result will be the same as in the source
chapters = OrderedDict()   # {chapter: [(lesson_name, lesson_link), ...], ...}

for item in lesson_outline:
    attributes = item.attrs
    try:
        class_type = attributes['class'][0]
        if class_type == 'chapter__title':
            chapter = item.text.strip()
            chapters[chapter] = []
        if class_type == 'chapter__exercise':
            lesson_name = item.find('h5').text
            lesson_link = item.find('a').attrs['href']
            chapters[chapter].append((lesson_name, lesson_link))
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

From there it should be easy to write your text file:

```
for chapter, lessons in chapters.items():
    # write chapter title
    for lesson_name, lesson_link in lessons:
        # write lesson
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was an elegant solution: Dictionary > list > tuple. Question: What was the reason you suggested an OrderedDictionary vs. a regular one? Does it have to do with how you access it in `.items()`?

Comment: Using `OrderedDict` assures that the order of the result will be the same as in the source. A standard `dict` doesn't guarantee this of you iterate over the keys or items.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!