# Is there a way to find an element in a list with a unique criteria Python?

Tags: python

For some reason .index and .find is not working in my program.

Basically, I want the program to find the index number of the list with the set criteria.

For example this list:

```
['Synonyms: Pocket Monsters, Indigo League, Adventures on the Orange Islands, The Johto Journeys, Johto League Champions, Master Quest', 'Japanese: ポケットモンスター', 'Type: TV', 'Episodes: 276', 'Status: Finished Airing', 'Aired: Apr 1, 1997 to Nov 14, 2002', 'Premiered: Spring 1997', 'Broadcast: Thursdays at 19:00 (JST)', 'Producers: TV Tokyo, TV Tokyo Music, Studio Jack', 'Licensors: VIZ Media, 4Kids Entertainment', 'Studios: OLM', 'Source: Game', 'Genres: Action, Adventure, Comedy, Kids, Fantasy', 'Duration: 24 min. per ep.', 'Rating: PG - Children', 'Score: 7.341 (scored by 291,570 users)', 'Ranked: #21572', 'Popularity: #287', 'Members: 504,076', 'Favorites: 4,076', '']
```

I would like to find the index number of the position of "Genres". I tried doing it .index("Genres:") but that didn't find the index number and returned an error.
I need this to find the index number because, for other pages on this website, the "genre" is in a different position

This is what I tried and just returned an error

```
GIndex = Information.index("Genres")
print (Information[GIndex])
Genre = (Information[GIndex])
```

Comment: There is no element with value `"Genres"` in list though.

Comment: Your data suggests that you'd be better of with a dict in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your list there is not element whose value is `"Genres"`. `"Genres"` and `"Genres: Action, Adventure, Comedy, Kids, Fantasy"` are not equal. If you want to find the element which starts with `"Genres"`, you can write a very simple for loop like

```
for index, item in enumerate(information_list):
   if item.startswith('Genres'):
      print(index, item)
      break
```

A better way would be like @9769953 suggested is to use a dictionary. The efficiency of lookup in dict is pretty much constant time and your data will be organized neatly with keys corresponding to property name and value corresponding to property value.

A dictionary would look like this

```
information_dict = {
  "Synonyms": "Pocket Monsters, Indigo League, Adventures on the Orange Islands, The Johto Journeys, Johto League Champions, Master Quest",
  "Japanese": "ポケットモンスター",
  "Type": "TV",
  "Episodes": "276",
  "Status": "Finished Airing",
  "Aired": "Apr 1, 1997 to Nov 14, 2002",
  "Premiered": "Spring 1997",
  "Broadcast": "Thursdays at 19:00 (JST)",
  "Producers": "TV Tokyo, TV Tokyo Music, Studio Jack",
  "Licensors": "VIZ Media, 4Kids Entertainment",
  "Studios": "OLM",
  "Source": "Game",
  "Genres": "Action, Adventure, Comedy, Kids, Fantasy",
  "Duration": "24 min. per ep.",
  "Rating": "PG - Children",
  "Score": "7.341 (scored by 291,570 users)",
  "Ranked": "#21572",
  "Popularity": "#287",
  "Members": "504,076",
  "Favorites": "4,076"
}
```

And by doing `information_dict["Genres"]` you can get the value `"Action, Adventure, Comedy, Kids, Fantasy"`.

Comment: This is what I'm aiming for but I don't know, to make python do it automatically since I'm using web scraping to get the information

Comment: @ametefe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659976/store-web-scraping-results-in-dataframe-or-dictionary Perhaps this can help.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused with the link provided.
Wouldn't I have to slide the string before the label and the information?
If it is that, I will encounter a problem because, on that website, different shows have slightly different HTML which can cause a problem.
Thanks anyways. I might a separate thread asking for help on dictionaries.

Comment: @ametefe We need more context for that. but I am certain it is definitely doable.

Comment: Is there a way to DM you here?

Comment: No. You need to post the question on the homepage. This way it can help other people too who have the same problem. Plus more people can help you as well @ametefe.

Comment: Cool thanks
I'll link you to the post when I post it

Comment: Adding a way to convert the list to the described dict would really improve the answer. `dict([tuple(s.split(": ", 1)) for s in information_list])` or `{k: v for k, v in (s.split(": ", 1) for s in x)}` + a small explanation that it splits each string only at the first occurrence of ": " and converts that to a dict. Without this, the part about handling a dict is far less helpful. For the comprehension, c.f., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308939/list-comprehensions-splitting-loop-variable

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
word = 'Genres'
results = [i for i, l in enumerate(lst) if word in l]
```

Answer (score 2):

for index to work it would need to be an exact match. This will check if 'Genres' is contained within any string in the list and print its index

```
word = 'Genres'
for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    if word in item:
        print(i, item)
```

you can easily turn this into a function to return i which is the index

Answer (score 2):

ou can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
l=['Synonyms: Pocket Monsters, Indigo League, Adventures on the Orange Islands, The Johto Journeys, Johto League Champions, Master Quest', 'Japanese: ポケットモンスター', 'Type: TV', 'Episodes: 276', 'Status: Finished Airing', 'Aired: Apr 1, 1997 to Nov 14, 2002', 'Premiered: Spring 1997', 'Broadcast: Thursdays at 19:00 (JST)', 'Producers: TV Tokyo, TV Tokyo Music, Studio Jack', 'Licensors: VIZ Media, 4Kids Entertainment', 'Studios: OLM', 'Source: Game', 'Genres: Action, Adventure, Comedy, Kids, Fantasy', 'Duration: 24 min. per ep.', 'Rating: PG - Children', 'Score: 7.341 (scored by 291,570 users)', 'Ranked: #21572', 'Popularity: #287', 'Members: 504,076', 'Favorites: 4,076', '']
for i, s in enumerate(l):
        if "Genres" in s:
              print(i)
>>>12
```

Comment: yep this is the way